# Magento2 how to get the payment method title instead of payment html in new order transaction email?

Tags: magento2, orders, email

How to get the payment method title instead of payment html raw in order transaction email in magento2

Comment: @Adrift, Thanks but i am taking about order email template.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I am using the following solution

```
<span>{{var order.getPayment().getMethodInstance().getTitle()}}</span>
```

Originally it was

```
{{var payment_html|raw}}
```

Now I am getting the payment method title only.

Comment: It is not working in Magento 2.4 versions.